# How can I check for depth of other texels in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, shadow, lighting

I am trying to work on a top-down perspective game, but am unsure of how to display things that the character (the ingame model) can see but the player cannot. For example, imagine a building that is in front of the character, and vertically below him on the screen. The character can see the wall of the building facing him, as well as the floor around it, but the player cannot as the building's roof and other sides are blocking it. I would like to know of the best way of rendering what the character can see and the player can't. In this case the player should be able to see the floor that is being blocked by the roof of the building. To illustrate what I mean I have created this drawing:

[image: If you can't see you aren't missing much]

Of course the character should be able to see the ground behind the building as well, but I felt that it would make it more difficult to understand the question then. What I thought of doing was creating a sort of cubemap except in 4 directions, ignoring up and down, from the character's perspective. Then render the scene from the top down perspective, but do no have a depth test. Then in the fragment shader check to see if the depth of the fragment from the player is the same as that in the cubemap (the same process as lighting) and draw the fragment if it is, and only draw it with half alpha if it's not. Is there a cheaper process to do this? I am also not sure if my method would work, as I have not tested it but I fear that I would run into issues where there is only one fragment in a location and so it would be the only thing rendered but at half transparency.

Answer (score 0):

I think the result of suggested method will look very strange, consider for instance next 2 cases:

1. you want to draw a fragment that is taken from the same building floor where your character is located, but the character doesn't see it(for example, it is a wall fragment obstructed by a piece of furniture from the characters perspective). How should this fragment be rendered?
2. Consider a ray cast from camera position into the direction of the building. This ray will intersect surface of the character's view volume in 0, 1, or what is also likely, 2 points. More than 2 intersections also can happen, since the view volume is concave. In this case there might be 2, or more opaque fragments generated with the same screen coordinates(corresponding to the ray cast). The result here is undefined, as the depth test is switched off.

I would suggest more classical approach, like: look which floor your character can see, render it and all floors below opaque, then render the top of the building transparent on the top of it, if you will.

Comment: But how would one check if the character can see the floor? What constitutes as seeing? Say the character is walking by a building with an open door. They can see a tiny bit into the building, but not much. Would the whole inner building get revealed? If not, then how much?